# How can I add and effectively delete google map markers with buttons?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple Thursday through Sunday button layout and I would like to be able to add markers (and subsequently remove them) based on which button is pressed. If Friday is pressed, it removes the existing markers (if there are any) and adds data tied to Friday. Here is my code:

```
function initialize() {

 var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: newYork,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function loadMarkers(val) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: val,
    map: map,
    title: "Hi there!"
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  $('#thurs').on('click', function() {
    if(!marker) {
      loadMarkers(newYork);
      console.log(marker);
    }
    else if(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
  });
})
```

On the first click, the marker is added; the second click removes the marker, but subsequent clicks do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to toggle the marker, you need to check:

1. if it doesn't exist, create it and add it to the map
2. if it exists, and is displayed on the map, hide it
3. if it exists, and is not displayed on the map, display it.

```
$('#thurs').on('click', function() {
  if(!marker || (marker.getMap() == null)) {
    loadMarkers(newYork);
    console.log(marker);
  }
  else if(marker && (marker.getMap() != null)) {
    marker.setMap(null);
  }
});
```

code snippet:

```js
var newYork = {
  lat: 40.7127837,
  lng: -74.0059413
};
var marker, map;

function initialize() {
  // New York, NY, USA (40.7127837, -74.00594130000002)
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: newYork,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function loadMarkers(val) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: val,
    map: map,
    title: "Hi there!"
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  $('#thurs').on('click', function() {
    if (!marker || (marker.getMap() == null)) {
      loadMarkers(newYork);
      console.log(marker);
    } else if (marker && (marker.getMap() != null)) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
  });
})
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="thurs" type="button" value="Thurs" />
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: By the way, thanks for the downvotes trolls. I can't ask questions now.